# Given a triangle $ABC$ with angle $ABC=120^\circ$, side $AB =10$ cm and median $BM =2$ cm, what is the length of $BC$?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

> Given a triangle $ABC$ with angle $ABC=120^\circ$, side $AB =10$ cm and median $BM =2$ cm, what is the length of $BC$?

[image: Construction of extended median]

Above I have attached a picture of what my approach to it was. I extedended the median $BM$ by $2$ times and obtained parallelogram $ABCD$. We then have $\angle BAD=60^\circ$.

Letting $\angle ADB=\theta$ and using the Sine Rule, I get
$$\frac{\sin(60^\circ)}{4}=\frac{\sin(\theta)}{10}$$

However, this does not seem to yield any real value for $\theta$. I was going to continue by then finding $\angle ABD$ and again applying the sine rule to find $AD$. Where did I go wrong in order to not obtain a real value for $\theta$?

Comment: That is a good attempt. I don't think you went wrong. There is something wrong with the question.

Comment: @yambourg. With AB=10 and $\angle ABC=120^o$ minimum value of median is 4.33, it can not be 2. The question is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way.

Let $BC=x$.

Thus, by law of cosines for $\Delta ADB$ we obtain:
$$x^2+100-2x\cdot10\cdot\frac{1}{2}=16.$$
Can you end it now?

I also got that it's impossible.

Comment: the equation you found has no real solution.The statement of question is not correct. the measure of median can not be 2.

Comment: Assuming median is equal to $m$, by your calculations we have $x^2-10x+100=4m^2$. minimum of LHS is $75$ hence minimum value of $m$ is $\dfrac{5\sqrt3}2\approx 4.33012>2$.